# Different pipes for different field names in NestJS

Tags: nestjs

I'm handling multiple audio files and an image file on a single request:

```js
@Post('create')
@UseInterceptors(AnyFilesInterceptor())
create(@UploadedFiles() files) {
    
}
```

I apply file type validation pipe for a single file like:

```js
@Post('request-for-verification')
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('documents'))
requestForVerification(@UploadedFile(new FileTypeValidationPipe('image')) documents: FileType) {
    
}
```

Now, I want to apply file type validation pipe according to the `fieldname` of the multipart form, i.e. `FileValidationPipe('image')` for `cover` field and `FileValidationPipe('audio')` for `songs` field.